# How do I get the state of a checkbox as variable into an ajax object

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a sweet google maps project I'm working on. I need to be able to click on certain checkboxes and have different pins dynamically appear. I have the ajax call and the database part working. I just can't get the ajax object to take in a variable or even read the checkbox object directly. Here is the object:

```
var $myCheckbox=jQuery("#myCheckbox").prop('checked');

var ajaxObj = { //Object to save cluttering the namespace.
    options: {
        url: pfp_catz_ajax_script.ajaxurl,  //The resource that delivers loc data.
        data: {
            action: 'pfp_catz_ajax',
            searchText: searchText,
            theFunction: 'getLocations',
            myCheckbox:$myCheckbox,            //I can't get anything into the variable
        },
        dataType: "json",   //The type of data to be returned by the server.
        type: 'POST'
    },
    delay: 1000,//(milliseconds) the interval between successive gets.
    errorCount: 0,//running total of ajax errors.
    errorThreshold: 5,//the number of ajax errors beyond which the get cycle should cease.
    ticker: null,//setTimeout reference - allows the get cycle to be cancelled with clearTimeout(ajaxObj.ticker);
    post: function(responseData) { //a function which initiates
        console.log('myCheckbox='+$myCheckbox);
        if(ajaxObj.errorCount < ajaxObj.errorThreshold) {
            ajaxObj.ticker = setTimeout(getMarkerData, ajaxObj.delay);
        }
    },
    fail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("This is the error: "+errorThrown);
        ajaxObj.errorCount++;
    }
};





//Ajax master routine
function getMarkerData() {
    jQuery.ajax(ajaxObj.options)
        .done(setMarkers) //fires when ajax returns successfully
        .fail(ajaxObj.fail) //fires when an ajax error occurs
        .always(ajaxObj.post); //fires after ajax success or ajax error
}

setMarkers(locs);//Create markers from the initial dataset served with the document.
ajaxObj.post();//Start the get cycle.




//myCheckbox listener event
jQuery("#legend").on('click', '#myCheckbox',function(){
    if(jQuery('#myCheckbox').is(':checked')) {
        alert('myCheckbox checked');
        $myCheckbox=1;
    }
    else {
        alert('myCheckbox unchecked');
        $myCheckbox=0;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post the request headers for this XHR?

Comment: I added the Ajax master routine to the bottom of the code.  Does that help?

Comment: For reference, here the original code I'm modeling my project after:
https://www.pushpendra.net/how-to-automatic-update-multiple-marker-position-on-google-map-dynamically-from-database-like-tracking-system/

Comment: Your variable stores the value at the time of, you need a checkbox listener to update the variable when changed

Comment: I tried that. See above in the listener I added.  Thanks for helping a stranger out.

Comment: Anyone? Anyone? Bueller....  Buller....